# TomCat Server and Ant

Tags: tomcat, ant

I am using windows 64-bit with tomcat 6 and ant 1.8.1 in the build.xml file (custom) when i execute the clean command to delete the directories and the war file nothing happens. I have to stop tomcat server delete the files manually and i can deploy from the ant that works but i cannot undeploy or do a clean from ant.

I recently installed windows 7 64bit and reinstall my applications and configured the machine. However i cannot undeploy the application from ant.

I took full ownership of the file directory and the tomcat user has manager-gui privileges.  Can anyone identify what i may need to do to undeploy the application. This worked fine on the 32 bit version of windows.

When i try ant undeploy its saying: "C:\SpringWorkSpace\crimeTrack\build.xml:257: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Darin\apache-tomcat-6.0\webapps\crimeTrack\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties"

**Code to deploy application :**

```
 <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

**Code to delete:**

```
<target name="clean" description="Clean output directories">
            <delete>            
                <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*.class"/>
                </fileset>
            </delete>
        </target>

        <target name="undeploy" description="Un-Deploy application">
            <delete>
                <fileset dir="${deploy.path}/${name}">
                    <include name="**/*.*"/>
                </fileset>
            </delete>
        </target>
```

Comment: Some class, certainly Log4J, is still accessing your log4j.properties file.

Comment: @StefanLindenberg +1. Seems like log4j.properties is in use while trying to delete (undeploy) the required directory.

Comment: i am not sure why this is happening since before it was working the code seems to be accurate.

Comment: btw in my ANT files I usually use `<delete dir="${deploy.dir}/${ant.project.name}" /><delete file="${deploy.dir}/${ant.project.name}.war" />`. (it's because Tomcat unpacks WAR file ...). But you code seems fine

Comment: for it to work i have to shut down tom cat. when i shut down the server and i undeploy the .war file remains and when i deploy it gets overwritten. Then i can restart the server and it will work but for every change i make i have to shut down the server. Is there some setting i need to change. My tomcat user role is manager-gui

Comment: Mine is: `<user name="manager" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script,admin" />`. And all work just fine.

Comment: informatik01 - what version of tomcat are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat version 7.0.32 on Windows 7 32 bit Professional